# How to create new button in Yiibooster TBGridview

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using Yiibooster and the TbGridView to show some results. I'm also using the following code to provide smart looking icons to a view, update and delete link.

```
array(
    'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
    'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/item/view", array("id"=>$data["id"], "sector" => $data["sector"]["slug"],"title" => $data["slug"]))',
    'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/item/update", array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
    'deleteButtonUrl'=>null,
)
```

What I'd like to do is basically be able to show another button in there or in replace of the delete button. I'm just unsure how (or where specifically) I need to code the values for the this button.

I'm currently looking at the TbButtonColumn.php file and tried just adding a button just to see if it would work it didn't.

What would be the correct process to to do this?

Thanks in advance

Jonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `buttons` parameter for additional buttons, it is [in docs od `CButtonColumns`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#c719), here is sample from link:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    // Template to set order of buttons
    'template' => '{postview} {preview}',
    // Buttons config
    'buttons' => array(
        'postview' => array(
            'label' => '...',     // text label of the button
            'url' => '...',       // the PHP expression for generating the URL of the button
            'imageUrl' => '...',  // image URL of the button. If not set or false, a text link is used
            'options' => array(...), // HTML options for the button tag
            'click' => '...',     // a JS function to be invoked when the button is clicked
        ),
        'preview' => array(
            // Another button config
        ),
    ),
),
```

NOTE: This is example for `CButtonColumn` but `TbButtonColumn` is a subclass of `CButtonColumn`, so everything applies to both.